# Retrieve all values from join?

Tags: python, django

I have 3 tables. `User, Post, and Share.` `Post` is a table that contains all posts. `Post` has a one to many relationship with `Share.` That being said, the `Share` table is a table where it indicates which posts a user has shared. Here's the structure of the tables:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    share_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url         = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Share(models.Model):
    post        = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shared_at   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Let's say we have a User with id 1. What I want to do is to show all posts + shares of that user ordered by date. Just like how Twitter does when you go to a User's Twitter profile. It shows all their Tweets + their Retweets ordered by date and time. What I've tried doing is this query:

```
Share.objects.all().select_related('post').get(user=1)
```

If I do this, I get an error that there is more than one share for this user. What am I doing wrong? 
The error:

> Example.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one
>   Share -- it returned 2!

Comment: `Share.objects.all().select_related('post').filter(user=1)` ?

Comment: @Rakesh Hmm, this is working, however, it's only getting user 1's shares and not their posts as well. I need to get user 1's shares and posts

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `get()` with `filter()`

See documentation for [get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) and [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Comment: Hmm, this is working, however, it's only getting user 1's shares and not their posts as well. I need to get user 1's shares and posts

Answer (score 1):

`.get()` will return an error if none or more than one object is returned. Use `.filter()` instead to get a QuerySet:

```
Share.objects.all().select_related('post').filter(user=1)
```

Comment: Hmm, this is working, however, it's only getting user 1's shares and not their questions as well. I need to get user 1's shares and questions

Comment: @user2896120, what questions? This gets you all the `Share` related to user 1. When you iterate through the shares, you can use `Share.post` to access the post and its attributes.

Comment: Sorry, it only shows the shares and not the posts of the user. For example, i want what the user shared + the user's posts. So a user couldve shared another user's posts and couldve also posted their own posts

Comment: If you want what the user shared: `Share.objects.filter(user=1)` If you want the user's posts: `Post.objects.filter(user=1)`

Comment: I want both the shared and user's posts, but the reason why I want it in one query is because i'm trying to get a total of 20 most recent shared + posts

Comment: You can't with one query, and that is not the original question. But I think you'll have to do 2 queries and get the 20 most recent on the side with Python. Like get the 20 most recent posts + 20 most recent shares then get the 20 most recent posts OR shares. You might be able to do that with annotate.